# How can I avoid misidentification of a exponential distribution as Gamma or Weibull?

Tags: r, distributions, p-value, fitting

I'm trying to write a piece of code in R that identifies a set of sample data as belonging to a specific distribution and pull the specific distribution parameters, by performing the K-S test and comparing the resulting p-values.

However, I've run into a bit of a logical problem. I can successfully generate gamma, weibull, logistic, normal and poisson distributions and correctly identify them, but as soon as I try to identify an exponential distribution, the resulting p-values are always lower than the p-values from trying to fit a weibull or gamma distribution. So, to put it another way, I generate a random set of values from an exponential distribtion using

```
rexp(1000)
```

but when I pass it through my code, the resulting p-values are, for instance:

```
[1,] "distribution" "ks pvalue"     
[2,] gamma          "0.850558314129566"
[3,] weibull        "0.833929454438442"
[4,] logistic       "0"                
[5,] normal         "0"                
[6,] exponential    "0.704115316673917"
[7,] poisson        "0"
```

The section of code that performs the test on the exponential distribution, for instance, is (credited with GREAT thanks to @TinaW from StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29855963/how-do-i-fit-distributions-to-sample-data-in-r/29858280)):

```
gf_shape    = "exponential"
fd_e        = fitdistr(data, "exponential")
est_rate    = fd_e$estimate[[1]]
ks          = ks.test(data, "pexp", rate=est_rate)
results[i,] = c(gf_shape, est_rate, "NA", ks$statistic, ks$p.value)
```

Do you guys have any idea what I'm doing wrong? I've tried increasing and decreasing the sample size, toying with the parameters, but the gamma and weibull p-values are always larger than that of the exponential fit. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you link to the [SO] thread w/ the complete code?

Comment: Note that the exponential is a special case of the Weibull, which is more flexible & would be able to better fit any exponential data despite its exponentiality (is that a word?). Are you taking that fact into account? If not, that may be (part of) the answer.

Comment: Hi @gung. Here is the thread where most of the code comes from. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29855963/how-do-i-fit-distributions-to-sample-data-in-r/29858280

Comment: @gung I'm not SPECIFICALLY taking that into account, but surely a random distribution specifically generated to fit the exponential function should better fit an exponential function than the (more general) Weibull function?

Comment: If you aren't taking that into account, then *no*. A more flexible model (distribution, here) will always fit better than a less flexible model irrespective of the fact that the latter is correct.

Comment: @gung thank you; I suspected as much, but wasn't quite sure if it was a conceptual problem or whether I just implemented it incorrectly. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Hmmm, I haven't even looked at the code, but if that's all you want I can turn that into an official answer.

Comment: What's most fundamentally wrong is trying to use p-values to compare distributions. That's not how p-values work. You might be able to use a conceptually similar but theoretically valid approach by comparing *likelihood ratios* rather than p-values.

Comment: @Martin Think of the following analogy: I have a set of data that's either from a normal distribution with mean 100 and variance 1 or from a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance 1. Now I generate data from a normal distribution with mean 100 and variance 1. Let's estimate parameters via MLE. Which of the two possibilities will fit better? The answer is (with probability 1) the second one - the more general case will *always* fit my data better (in the sense that the likelihood will be greater, for example). [The exponential is a special case of both the more general distributions.]

Comment: The problem is using p-values to make that choice.  You might want to consider a Bayesian approach, perhaps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the [exponential distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) is a [special case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Related_distributions) of the [Weibull distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution) the Weibull's shape parameter equals $1$.  Thus, the Weibull is more flexible and would be able to better fit any exponential data despite the data's exponentiality (is that a word?). If you are not taking that into account, that may be (part of) the answer. A more flexible model (distribution, here) will always fit better than a less flexible model irrespective of the fact that the latter is correct.

Comment: Similarly, the exponential is a special case of the gamma....